# How to prevent a second click in a radio button that´s checked?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

How to prevent a second click on a radio button that´s already checked?

The ideia is to deny the possibility of clicking again in the same radio button.

Regards,
RG

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this?

Comment: Because i´m building a custom cart system, and when i click on a radio an item it´s added to the cart and total, but if i click twice (not doubleclick) in the same radio button the item it´s removed but the total doesn´t update, only when when i click in the other radio options that occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent the event if it has been clicked before:

```
var clicked = false;
$('input:radio.yourclass').click(function(event){
     if (clicked){
         event.preventDefault();
     }
     clicked = true;
});
```

You could also disable it, but then it's value is not posted to the server - if you need control over more buttons, it can be done, please provide your markup

Example here = http://jsfiddle.net/LUkw9/1/

Comment: Is there a guarantee that on the second click this event will fire earlier than the default?

Comment: preventDefault() prevents the default action of the click (following a link for anchors, submitting a form for a submit) the second click is obviously after the first and the default action (ticking a radio button) is prevented

Comment: then you need `if (!clicked)`, so that default is prevented during the first click processing. But this way you'll need a guarantee that default handler has already worked before this one works.

Comment: On the first click i just set the variable clicked to true. On the second (and all the others) i also prevent the default behaviour. I don't think i need that second if.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to the function that is executed when the radio-button is clicked

```
jQuery("#parentElement input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
```

Instead of

```
input:radio
```

---

you might also target a specific id for a radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="example1" id="example1">
<input type="radio" name="example2" id="example2">
```

With this

```
('#example2').click(function(){
alert("handling radiobutton, complete!");
jQuery("#example1").attr('disabled',false);
jQuery("#example2").attr('disabled',true);});
```

This is a bit quick (but not nececerly dirty) of course, and you should loop trough them if the form has an unknown number of radio-buttons.

Comment: If you disable it, it's value is not posted

Comment: Correct, make sure this is executed after the value is posted.

Comment: Well, but he nedds to disable the button when it is clicked, so that the user can click a radio button only once

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but the result it´s not exactly what i need. I need to ensure that if a radio button is checked the user can´t click it again, but the other radio buttons must keep available to choose.

Comment: Thank you for the sample, it´s almost this but... i need to enable the radio button himself if it´s checked.
And what about that 'little' detail that if it´s disabled the value it´s not posted?

Comment: Enable it on check? How is that? Or do you mean to keep it enabled when clicked?

Comment: sorry, i don´t express correctly, i need that the other radio buttons keep enabled and the checked one disabled (like toggle).

Comment: My example does that. Simply give the other radio's another id, and restore the first on their click, if you wish to re-enable them.